# Python inheritance woes

Tags: python

This is a homework question, but as you can see I've written most of the code already. :)  What I'm trying to have happen is that the **Agent** object inherits the methods from the **Investor** object, as the **Agent** object's methods are suppose to be basically the same. The only different is the constructors, **Investor** takes 6 parameters, **Agent** takes 7. You can see that the parameters are also basically the same.

**Investor.load** and **Investor.report** work, for the most part, as expected. The inherited methods in **Agent** do not. See below.

My main issues:

1. When I run **report(o)** on **Investor**, the output is slightly messed up. It has little paragraph symbols at the end of each line, rather than a carriage return. (I'm developing on linux)
2. When I run **load** and **report** on **Agent**, it does not populate my arrays (**reports** and **data**) as it should. Because of that, **report** prints nothing. How do I set up my class variables so that they work in the way I want them to?

Thanks!

***Will re-add after turnin date.***

Here is how the above code **SHOULD** function.

```
>>> from sys import stdout as o
>>> import datetime
>>> from hedgefunds import *
>>>
>>> i = Investor('Flintstone','Fred',datetime.date(1965,12,3),'male','Mr.')
>>>
>>> i
Investor('Flintstone', 'Fred', datetime.date(1965, 12, 3), 'male', 'Mr.', 1)
>>> repr(i)
"Investor('Flintstone', 'Fred', datetime.date(1965, 12, 3), 'male', 'Mr.', 1)"
>>> i.__repr__()  # THIS CONTROLS PREVIOUS TWO LINES
"Investor('Flintstone', 'Fred', datetime.date(1965, 12, 3), 'male', 'Mr.', 1)"
>>> eval(repr(i))  # OBJECT CAN BE RECREATED FROM ITS REPR STRING
Investor('Flintstone', 'Fred', datetime.date(1965, 12, 3), 'male', 'Mr.', 1)
>>>
>>> i  # NOTICE ONE ADDITIONAL BIT OF DATA WE DIDN'T SPECIFY?
Investor('Flintstone', 'Fred', datetime.date(1965, 12, 3), 'male', 'Mr.', 1)
>>> # THE '1' AT THE END IS THE RECORD ID rid. THE REPR STRING INCLUDES ALL DATA SO YOU SEE IT.
>>> # THE INVESTOR CLASS SHOULD ASSIGN A rid IF ONE IS NOT PASSED INTO THE CONSTRUTOR.
>>>
>>> print i
1, Mr. Fred Flintstone, 12/03/1965, male
>>> i.__str__()  # THIS CONTROLS PREVIOUS LINE
'1, Mr. Fred Flintstone, 12/03/1965, male'
>>>
>>> # NOTE THE NAME IS NICELY PUT TOGETHER AND AND rid IS AT THE START
>>> # NOTE datetime.date(YYYY, MM, DD) BUT WE PRINT IN  MM/DD/YYYY FORMAT
>>>
>>> # NOW LET'S LOOK AT OUR INVESTOR OBJECT'S ATTRIBUTES
>>> i.last_name
'Flintstone'
>>> i.first_name
'Fred'
>>> i.dob
datetime.date(1965, 12, 3)
>>> i.date_of_birth
'12/03/1965'
>>> i.gender
'male'
>>> i.title
'Mr.'
>>> i.name
'Mr. Fred Flintstone'
>>> i.rid
1 
>>>
>>> # BUT WE'RE GONNA NEED SOMEHWERE TO STORE MULTIPLE INVESTOR OBJECTS
>>> # SO AS WELL AS CREATING INVESTOR OBJECTS, THE INVESTOR CLASS MUST ACT LIKE A RECORDSET
>>>
>>> Investor.report(o)  # o WAS SET TO STDOUT AT THE TOP OF THIS TRACE BUT COULD BE ANY FILE
>>> Investor.add(i)  # NO RECORDS SO LET'S ADD ONE
>>> Investor.report(o)  # NOW WE HAVE SOMETHING TO REPORT
1, Mr. Fred Flintstone, 12/03/1965, male
>>>
>>> Investor.add(Investor('Flintstone','Wilma',datetime.date(1968,1,15),'female','Mrs.'))
>>> Investor.report(o)
1, Mr. Fred Flintstone, 12/03/1965, male
2, Mrs. Wilma Flintstone, 01/15/1968, female
>>>

>>> # WE COULD CONTINUE ADDING INVESTORS MANUALLY BUT SINCE WE'VE GOT A FILE FULL OF THEM....
>>> Investor.load('investors.csv')
>>> Investor.report(o)
1, Mr. Charles Creed, 12/05/1928, male
2, Miss Sheila Geller, 11/12/1962, female
3, Mr. Fred Kenobi, 07/13/1957, male
4, Miss Rachel Geller, 07/11/1968, female
5, Mr. Charles Rubble, 09/23/1940, male
6, Mrs. Leah Skywalker, 07/02/1929, female
7, Mr. Bill Balboa, 03/06/1988, male
8, Dr. Sheila Barkley, 08/26/1950, female
.
.
>>> # YOU SHOULD SEE 120 RECORDS (OUR TWO MANUALLY ADDED RECORDS ARE GONE)
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> # AGENTS
>>>
>>> a = Agent(2.1,'Rubble','Barney',datetime.date(1966,4,20),'male','Mr.')
>>> a
Agent(2.1000000000000001, 'Rubble', 'Barney', datetime.date(1966, 4, 20), 'male', 'Mr.', 1)
>>> repr(a)
"Agent(2.1000000000000001, 'Rubble', 'Barney', datetime.date(1966, 4, 20), 'male', 'Mr.', 1)"
>>> eval(repr(a))
Agent(2.1000000000000001, 'Rubble', 'Barney', datetime.date(1966, 4, 20), 'male', 'Mr.', 1)
>>> print a
1, Mr. Barney Rubble, 04/20/1966, male, 2.1
>>> a.last_name
'Rubble'
>>> a.first_name
'Barney'
>>> a.dob
datetime.date(1966, 4, 20)
>>> a.date_of_birth
'04/20/1966'
>>> a.gender
'male'
>>> a.title
'Mr.'
>>> a.name
'Mr. Barney Rubble'
>>> a.rid
1
>>> a.commission
2.1000000000000001
>>> Agent.add(a)
>>> Agent.report(o)
1, Mr. Barney Rubble, 04/20/1966, male, 2.1
>>> Agent.load('agents.csv')
>>> Agent.report(o)
1, Mr. Barney Flintstone, 02/13/1933, male, 4.0
2, Miss Rachel Rubble, 11/21/1982, female, 2.5
3, Dr. Ted Geller, 03/14/1963, male, 8.0
4, Miss Phoebe Creed, 11/06/1959, female, 5.5
5, Mr. Luke Kenobi, 08/24/1945, male, 2.5
6, Dr. Megan Creed, 03/26/1957, female, 5.5
7, Mr. Ted Rubble, 09/14/1931, male, 3.5
8, Mrs. Monica Balboa, 05/07/1934, female, 1.5
```

Comment: I was going to test this, and it said you're missing colons in your load method of Investor at the end of the if statements

Comment: Eh, sorry. Had to cut out some code to make it readable. It's just the colons after the if statements. Corrected. Test it now! :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to learn Python, so I figured I would lurk about SO and see the answers to people's questions. Also, you declared reports and data inside the init method. Wouldn't that make them local variables?

Comment: Be careful when declaring mutable variables that are class variables and not instance variables.  Specifically, in your `__init__` you probably want to assign like so: `self.reports, self.data = [], []`.  This will ensure that every instance of Agent and Investor end up with their own new lists.  Otherwise, you may have variable confusion.

Comment: @g.d.d.c, What about `self.reports=self.data=[]`

Comment: @GDDC: Changing reports = [] to self.reports = [] in the __init__ didn't help, resulted in an error actually!

Comment: I'd also suggest, rather than your lines of `result = result + str(ele) + ', '` you use something like `', '.join([str(e) for e in x])`.  It's cleaner and more concise that manually constructing the string and then attempting to chop off the end of it (which can actually be done with `result[:-3]` if there's a reason you're not comfortable with `join()`).

Comment: @Anyone: See anything else... anyone?

Comment: @GDDC: Ooh, result[:-3]? Nice! Python does make me happy sometimes, just sometimes...

Comment: @g.d.d.c I was under the impression from his previous question he _wants_ those to be class level variables. CODe - You should either be creating `self.reports` and `self.data` in `__init__` or `data` and `reports` in the class (which automatically makes them on the class, even though it does't look like it), not both, and definitely not just `data` and `reports` in `__init__`.

Comment: CODe did you try just completely removing `add` etc. from `Agent`? The methods on `Investor` will be called automatically if they don't exist, that's the whole point of inheritance.

Comment: @agf - hence my warning - using mutable variables as class level variables can lead to confusion.  If they're class level, not instance, all instance share the same actual list, which may not be what he expects.

Comment: @agf: You might be right about the class variables. Also, I'll try removing add.

Comment: CODe also `report` and `load`, not just `add`. Also, I was still editing that last comment directed to you and g.d.d.c, make sure to re-read it.

Comment: @agf: Didn't work. New errors! :(

Comment: CODe - Do you want all the agents and investors to share one `data` and one `reports`? Or one for all the agents, and one for all the investors? Or one for each agent, and one for each investor?

Comment: @agf: I'm going to add some use cases, so you can see how they should behave.

Comment: @agf: Added use cases. I believe the ***classes*** should have their own storage containers, not the object. Therefore, Agent and Investor should have their own container.

Comment: CODe - Yes, that looks correct to me. I've added an answer with three suggestions to correct / simplify your code. I don't know if they'll fix your problem but they should help you find it. The second point is the main one -- make sure to fix your references to `records` and `data` as I suggested, especially in `__init__`.

Comment: Also, you edited your old post to remove your code because your professor told you to, then you ask a new question with more code in it? Bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot going on here, so I'll try to be brief.

```
class Investor(object):
    reports = []
    data = []

    def __init__(self, LastName, FirstName, Date, Gender, Title, Rid=1):
        # the following two lines define variables which only exist inside
        # __init__, so they can basically be gotten rid of.
        # reports = []
        # data = []
        # but they *don't need to be initialized*. Actually creating a new list
        # in each constructor is *bad* unless you want one report per instance

        # ... later, be sure to add "self" instead of adding to the local vars
        self.add(self)

    @classmethod
    def report(self, o):
        result = ""
        for x in self.reports:
            # Just use join, that's what you mean anyway.
            result = ', '.join(x)
            # \n should result in \n\n. I think you mean o.write(result)
            o.write(result + "\n")

    @classmethod
    def load(self, f):
        self.reports = []
        self.data = []
        file = open(f)
        # why the extra readline?
        file.readline()
        list = []
        while 1:
            line = file.readline()
            # you need to get rid of the trailing whitespace
            items = line[:-1].split(", ")
            if not line:
                break
            else:
                # self, here, refers to the class, so you can use it as the
                # constructor as well
                # use the * to make a list into an argument list.
                self(*items)
                # No need to add it, the value is added at the end of __init__
                # as things stand.

class Agent(Investor):
    reports = []
    data = []

    def __init__(self, Commission, LastName, FirstName, \
                       Date, Gender, Title, Rid=1):
        super(Agent, self).__init__(self, LastName, FirstName, Date, \
                                          Gender, Title, Rid)
        self.commission = Commission

    def __str__(self):
        # Be lazy! Use super!
        return super(Agent,self).__str__() + ', ' + self.commission

    # this was doing the same thing in the parent class.
    # def __repr__(self):

    # The classmethod methods are not needed unless you want to redefine 
    # behavior in a child class.
    @classmethod
    def add(self, i):
        # If you do change something, though, make sure to use super
        # here as well...
        super(Agent, self).add(i)
```

I believe that should take care of most of your issues.

If you want to have the format `Investor('Flintstone', 'Fred', datetime.date(1965, 12, 3), 'male', 'Mr.', 1)`, you'll need to include the `__name__` and quote the properties:

```
def __repr__(self):
    # notice the " and ' below.
    return self.__name__ + "('" + str(self.rid) + "', '" + \
           self.name + "', " + self.date_of_birth + ", '" + self.gender + "')"
```

In Agent you will need to use a sub-string to get what you need:

```
def __repr__(self):
   # remove the Agent( so you can add the commission at the *front* 
   s = super(Agent,self).__str__()
   return self.__name__ + "('" + self.commission + "'," + \
          s[len(self.__name__ + 1):]
```

Comment: `load` is a classmethod, so `self` is actually the class object, so `self.__class__` is wrong.

Comment: @agf: He doesn't mind us getting help, he was worried someone else would see my code posted online and copy it. Way to make incorrect assumptions, I was going to mark yours as the correct answer too!

Comment: @CODe If I was worried about points, I wouldn't have deleted it. I'll remove my comment though.

Comment: @agf: Not a problem either way. Your suggestions didn't solve my problems. I found the answer myself and will repost after the turnin date to avoid anyone copying my code.